# Get notified when power goes off at remote location

Tags: email, power-supply, notifications, sms

I am running a small office of upto 10 computers with normal UPS for each system. Power cut is casual in my area I stay and I could not afford to inverters or generators. Some computers(linux & windows) will be running all time along with server in my office which are accessed directly or remotely. The systems are abruptly shut down automatically after having discharged the ups power during power cut and I am wondering if I could have some kind of software or something where by I get notified by SMS or mail when power goes off in my office so that I can shut them down remotely. Anybody has any idea, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a UPS that has a USB connection and can warn the attached computer when it's running on batteries and how much time is left.  Modern OSes all have the ability to shut down safely when battery power is detected/low.  look for it under "power" options in your OSes control panel/settings.  Many also have the ability to run arbitrary scripts or send email... Just make sure your networking gear is also on UPS or the email will get nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @Chris Nava says, I would have a larger UPS on the serevr and protect  the switches/router with the same UPS.  Most will have software that not only shuts down gracefully and manages startup but can also send e-mail and other messages.  Most APC SmartUPS come with PowerChute that will manage 5 systems.  You can configure the messages in many ways and you would then know as soon as power is off.